# WebDriver/Ruby test reporting?

Tags: ruby, testing, webdriver, automated-tests

My team is currently building a WebDriver test framework in Ruby. We are looking for a way to generate test completion reports so they can be emailed out, ideally included individual test and test verification point results.

As an example of what I mean when I say test verification points, a test which creates a product could have multiple verification points such as did the product name get created correctly, did the product price get created correctly. If the test completion report could specify which verification point failed it would make assessing failures a lot quicker.

The reports that can be output from the selenium IDE are pretty much what I'm after.

Comment: are you using any test framework ? ex: Rspec

Comment: No, we're not using any framework, we're using Ruby and WebDriver to do through the UI automation (things like placing orders, giving refunds etc) to cut down on the amount of manual testing we currently require.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Ruby, you can use consider storing your verification points outcomes, test case status etc in a DB such as MySQL or Sqlite.  This gives you the ability to perform various analysis on the health of your tests in the past and present. Based on this you can even predict the future trend.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Allure report](http://allure.qatools.ru/) and respective [RSpec adapter](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-rspec) could suit your requirements? This report is rather new and gives you wide range of features like grouping tests by BDD features and stories, saving attachments, parameters and so on.